# How do you send an invoice to a customer by email in Odoo 10

Tags: odoo

I can not find how to send -via email- an invoice to a customer. It is clear how to send a quote to a customer or a purchase order to a provider as both actions are incorporated into the flow, but I can not find a way to send an invoice to a customer or a provider.

Is there any configuration settings or addon module to achieve this?

Odoo 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go the accounting menu in Odoo. You will find the customer invoices menu under sales.

[image: Invoice menu]

You will find the list of invoices like the below

[image: list of invoices]

Select any one invoice and validate it.

[image: invoice validation]

After the validation you fill a button called *send by email*, click on that and send the Invoice by email.

[image: send invoice by email]

Comment: Nice answer. Could you please add the second option, which is always possible if the "Odoo chatter" is present?

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to find the button once the invoice is marked as Paid. Button is only present in state "open" (which makes sense).